# При запуске библиотеки в решении терминал выдает ошибку С#

Tags: c#, dll

Работаю на mac в  Visual Studio. 
 1. Создал библиотеку (простая (умножение/деление/вычитание/сложение)
 2. Добавил ее к консольному приложению, запустил ее без отладки.

На это терминал выдал мне такое сообщение:

> Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'MyLibrary, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system cannot find the file specified.

Судя по нему он не нашел библиотеку, хотя я ее добавил (но мог наверно где то ошибиться) Прилогаю скрин экрана, что бы было видно где она лежит.
[image: Экран с кодом c#]

Comment: Хочу дополнить, что приложение завелось. Но только после того как я подключил библиотеку как проект.

Comment: `using MyLibrary;`